# How to Choose A Random Number From An Array Using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jsx

I am doing a clone of Netflix using React.js for learning React.js. I integrated an API from TMDb and for the case of banner image , name , and description , I have an array of 20 Objects which contains all details of 20 movies , and when the page is refreshed , I need to change the Banner into another random movie in the array. I don't Know how to select a random object by its number. Please Help Me To do this.

Here Is My Code :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Banner.css'
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import {API_KEY,imageUrl} from '../../Constants/Constants'
import axios from '../../Axios'

function Banner() {
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data);
            setMovie(response.data.results[11])
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="banner" style={{backgroundImage:`url(${movie ? imageUrl+movie.backdrop_path : ""})`}}>
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="title">{movie ? movie.title : ""}</h1>
                <div className="banner-buttons">
                    <button className="button">Play</button>
                    <button className="button">My List</button>
                </div>
                <h1 className="description">{movie ? movie.overview : ""}</h1>
            </div> 
            <div className="fade-bottom"></div>                               
        </div>
    )
}

export default Banner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.random()` which gives you a random number between 0 and 1. You then multiply it by the length of the resulting array and you round it to the lower integer using `Math.floor()`. You now have a random integer in the proper range that can be used to extract an element from the array itself.

```
const results = response.data.results
const newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)

setMovie(results[newIndex])
```

Comment: But It Says 'response' is not defined ??

Comment: I based that on your example code: `setMovie(response.data.results[11])`.  You should be able to adjust it accordigly to your actual data structure